# DateAdd function inside an IIF expression not working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I'm working on a SSRS document and use a DateAdd inside an IIF expression as the value of one of the fields. It goes like this:

```
=IIF((Sum(Fields!Promo_BLen.Value) - Sum(Fields!Promo_Plan.Value)) >= "0" ,  DateAdd("s",Sum(Fields!Promo_BLen.Value) - Sum(Fields!Promo_Plan.Value),"00:00:00") , DateAdd("s",Sum(Fields!Promo_Plan.Value) - Sum(Fields!Promo_BLen.Value),"00:00:00"))
```

The values of the fields are nums which I then format to "00:00:00" time format. For some reason I keep getting an error.
Also if its any help I'm working on VisualSudio 2013

Any clues?

Comment: So you're adding a number of seconds to a string?  Have you tried converting `"00:00:00"` to a datetime instead of a string first?

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests with similar formulas and came up with something. It seems that if even if you reach one output (the "condition is true" part), it still attempts calculates the other output. And if you do DATEADD("s", -1, "00:00:00") then you get an error.

With what you're trying to do, I suggest this solution : =DATEADD("s", ABS(Sum(Fields!Promo_Plan.Value) - Sum(Fields!Promo_BLen.Value)),"00:00:00")

Comment: Did its charm, Thanks alot.